# the text is cut in the rmarkdown pdf file

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

As you can see in the picture, the text is cut at the end of the page, What could be the solution here to prevent this? I have executed

````
---
title: "simulation"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: yes
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(report)
```



```{r}
model_1 <- glm(vs ~ mpg * drat, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
report(model_1)

```
````

the code in the header.tex for the Yaml header

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Confidential - \url{www.Google.com}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
\lhead{Google- Google - \today}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}
```

The warning I get to eventually how fix the problem but, haven't been able to solve it

```
Warning: (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{46.08408pt}.
Warning: (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:
Warning: (fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-5.63133pt}.
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Possibly this solves your question: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html

Comment: Can you add `keep_tex: true` to your header and share the intermediate .tex file? You probably want to redefine something like the highlight or shaded environment to use `lstlistings` which allows line breaks in verbatim material.

Comment: Thank you for the help, its fixed now, I added \lstset{breaklines=true} in the latex file